# JSF 2, primefaces 4. outputLabel doesn't work in dynamic tabs

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How can you label p:inputText field with p:outputLabel in dynamic tabs. The following code doesn't seem to work because p:outputLabel can't find specified id.

```
<h:form>
    <p:tabView id="tbw" value="#{mngr.numbers}" var="number">
       <p:tab id="tabId#{number}">
           <h:panelGrid columns="2"  >
               <p:outputLabel value="Name" for="inId#{number}" />
               <p:inputText id="inId#{number}" value="#{mngr.string}" required="true"/>
           </h:panelGrid>
       </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>    
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that `id` is evaluated when JSF builds component tree for the view (view build time) and `var` of `<p:tabView>` is evaluated when view is rendered as HTML (view render time). As the latter happens to be executed at a later phase than the former, when JSF tries to access the `number` exported variable when evaluating `id`, it is at that point simply null, as it hasn't run at all.

You either need to leave changes in `id` altogether and let JSF/PrimeFaces autogenerate the necessary and right ids for them and let the label point to the right HTML element (you can inspect the generated HTML in browser's tools to find out that it is in fact generated correctly):

```
<p:tabView id="tbw" value="#{mngr.numbers}" var="number">
    <p:tab id="tabId">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Name" for="inId" />
            <p:inputText id="inId" value="#{mngr.string}" required="true" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

or, as an alternative, if for some unknown reason you wouldn't like to use this feature of JSF/PrimeFaces components, you need to have a view build time tag to generate the tabs when view is being built:

```
<p:tabView id="tbw">
    <c:forEach items="#{mngr.numbers}" var="number">
        <p:tab id="tabId#{number}">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Name" for="inId#{number}" />
                <p:inputText id="inId#{number}" value="#{mngr.string}" required="true" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>
    </c:forEach>
</p:tabView>
```

In the first case the ids will look like `tbw:_iterationIndex_:tabId`, where `_iterationIndex_` is the 0-based current iteration index of a `var`, and in the second case the will look like `tbw:tabId_number_`, where `_number_` is your number taken from your bean.

Also, beware that the second alternative has the caveat that it [breaks view scoped beans when used with Mojarra versions lighter than 2.1.18](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers).